# How can I target the response from an ajax to a specific div that was clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, ajax

I am trying to get an image loaded and displayed in a particular 
slot depending on where I click, Say **view1**, **view2** or **view3** as shown below.

I have set up a form with div elements and I want to use ajax to 
post and process a browsed image that I select using the

How can I pass the appropriate target: `id` name to the JavaScript to 
display the image in the correct location? My scripts are shown below.

```
<form class = "ajaxform" method="post" 
    enctype = "multipart/form-data" 
    action  = 'upload.php'>
    <div id='view1' onclick="triggerFileUpload('photo')>view1</div>
    <div id='view2' onclick="triggerFileUpload('photo')>view2</div>
    <div id='view3' onclick="triggerFileUpload('photo')>view3</div>
    <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="photo" />
</form>

<script type="text/javascript" >
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $('#photo').live('change', function() {
        $(".ajaxform").ajaxForm({
           target: '#view'
        }).submit();
    });
});
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    function triggerFileUpload(f){
        document.getElementById(f).click();
    }
</script>
```

Comment: You are using jQuery already, so stop with the old-school `onclick` attribute type of event handling, bind your event handlers in the “proper” jQuery way instead – and then you will automatically have access to the element that the event was triggered on in the handler function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Ninjakannon/htkzocrq/1/)

You can attach events to the target `div`s using jQuery's click method and get the `id` from `event.target.id`. I'm not sure of the specifics of what you are trying to do, but I hope something along the lines of the following will suffice.

**HTML**

```
<form class = "ajaxform" method="post" 
    enctype = "multipart/form-data" 
    action  = 'upload.php'>
    <div id='view1' class='photo-target'>view1</div>
    <div id='view2' class='photo-target'>view2</div>
    <div id='view3' class='photo-target'>view3</div>
    <input type="file" name="imagefile" id="photo" />
</form>
```

**JavaScript**

```
function createObjectURL(object) {
    return (window.URL) ? window.URL.createObjectURL(object) : window.webkitURL.createObjectURL(object);
}

function revokeObjectURL(url) {
    return (window.URL) ? window.URL.revokeObjectURL(url) : window.webkitURL.revokeObjectURL(url);
}

$(document).ready(function() {
    var photoTarget = null;

    $('#photo').on('change', function(event) {
        var src = createObjectURL(this.files[0]);
        var image = new Image();
        image.src = src;
        image.onload = function() {
            revokeObjectURL(this.src);
        };

        $("#" + photoTarget).append(image);
        $(".ajaxform").ajaxForm({
            target: '#view'
        }).submit();
    });

    $('.photo-target').click(function (event) {
        photoTarget = event.target.id;
        $("#photo").click();
    });
});
```

Comment: Or use `$(this).attr('id')` in the click-handler. Don't know which would be better.

Comment: Thank you so much this has worked so perfectly.  I have adopted the code as follows:

Comment: ....
        $(".ajaxform").ajaxForm({
            target: "#" + photoTarget
        }).submit();
    });
    $('.photo-target').click(function (event) {
        photoTarget = event.target.id;
  //this is needed on the server side to name the image
        document.getElementById('keyid').value=photoTarget;
        $("#photo").click();
    });
});

Comment: I am glad this worked for you :) I would greatly appreciate it if you would [accept the answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) (by clicking the tick on the left of my post underneath the arrows). Thank you.

Comment: This was my very first question to Stackoverflow so I did not know what to do.  Thank you so much.